# Passphrase wireguard/Firezone

Tags: linux, vpn, wireguard, passphrase

I created different users through firezone to use wireguard vpn. So I have the user, and the "device" in which I define the accessible IPs, and the DNS to use.
But to make things even more secure, I would like users to have a passphrase and for this to be requested each time the tunnel is activated.

Does this passphrase correspond to the password created when I add a user? And if so, how to have it at each connection? because the labels "once, every hour, every day etc are a bit fuzzy...

THANKS